# Getting SwiftUI bindings right in a custom view

Tags: binding, swiftui

I'm playing around with creating custom views for SwiftUI and am missing something about how bindings work.  I have the following code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var number: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NumberPicker(format: "%02d", max: 20, value: $number)
            Text("You picked \(number)")
        }
    }
}

struct NumberPicker: View {
    var format: String = "%d"
    var max: Int

    @Binding var value: Int

    var valueProxy: Binding<String> {
        Binding<String>(
            get: { String(format: self.format, self.$value.wrappedValue) },
            set: { self.value = Int(String($0))! }
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        Picker("", selection: valueProxy) {
            ForEach(0..<max) { item in
                Text(String(format: self.format, item))
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 40, height: 175)
        .clipped()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(number: 5)
    }
}
```

When I run this (either in the preview or simulator) the view doesn't automatically select `05` at startup as I would expect.  Also, manipulating the picker does not update the `Text` view below it.  From what I've read, I feel like this ought to work but maybe I'm missing something obvious?  Or am I going about this the wrong way?  This is using Xcode 11.3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your `Picker`'s `selection` value. You should use the `@Binding var value: Int` instead of `valueProxy` because `value` of your `NumberPicker` view is connected with `number` of your `ContentView`. So when you change `value` you will also change `number`.

If you want the `Picker` to start with the number 5, you need to start `number` with 5 instead of 0.

The code would be like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var number: Int = 5

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NumberPicker(format: "%02d", max: 20, value: $number)
            Text("You picked \(number)")
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct NumberPicker: View {
    var format: String = "%d"
    var max: Int

    @Binding var value: Int

    var body: some View {
        Picker("", selection: $value) {
            ForEach(0..<max) { item in
                Text(String(format: self.format, item))
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 40, height: 175)
        .clipped()
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked.  In my code above, I was setting the value of `number` to 5 in the preview creation code.  So all this was due to the unnecessary value proxy.  Overcomplicating things again...  